# Custom Recipes in Minecraft Modpack (other Error)

Tags: minecraft-modding

I want to have a new Recipe with crafttweaker, which using machines from the create mod, for Netherrack like this [image: Compacting Netherrack]
Im playing Mc 1.16.5

At the moment I tryed this code in \scripts\MyRecipes.zs:

```
import crafttweaker.api.registries.IRecipeManager;

<recipetype:create:compacting>.addRecipe("compact_netherrack", "none", [<item:minecraft:netherrack> * 8], [<item:minecraft:cobblestone> * 8, <item:minecraft:nether_wart>], [<fluid:minecraft:lava> * 10], 100);
```

but when I go into the world I get this errors:

```
[Error] Parser Exception @ MyRecipes.zs:3:0 : No such member: addRecipe
[Error] Scripts are invalid!
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: Make sure you have the CreateTweaker mod (CraftTweaker addon) installed. https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/createtweaker

Answer (score 1):

The error text is telling you that it does not have the method `addRecipe`, or at least the system is unable to find it.

The [Create Compacting](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.16/en/mods/Create/Compacting) article says:

> The Compacting mechanic is a type of IRecipeManager and implements all the methods that are available to IRecipeManager's, such as removeRecipe() and removeAll().

We can confirm that [`IRecipeManager`](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.16/en/vanilla/api/managers/IRecipeManager) does not have an `addRecipe` method.

So we want some type that extends `IRecipeManager`, adding some things, presumably adding the missing `addRecipe`. Sadly the article quoted above does not say the name of the class we need. It only refers to it as "The Compacting mechanic".

Searching for `<recipetype:create:compacting>` I found [`CompactingManager`](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.18/en/mods/createtweaker/CompactingManager), which lists among its methods [`addRecipe`](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.18/en/mods/createtweaker/CompactingManager#addRecipe).

So, I believe you need to import `CompactingManager`:

```
import mods.create.CompactingManager;
```

Comment: the wiki say that add Recipe should work (https://docs.blamejared.com/1.16/en/mods/Create/Compacting)
when i use the CompactingManager the same error and "could not find mods.create.CompactingManager" comes
I have added that I'm playing minecraft 1.16.5 maybe there are diffrents

Comment: @opensource25 I don't know if it is a version issue, but I doubt that is the case. How about the CreateTweaker the wiki mentions on the red box at the top, do you have that installed?

Comment: @opensource25 It appears that it is possible to do the same thing with `addJSONRecipe` (except `addRecipe` seems to be meant to provide a friendlier API), but since `addJSONRecipe` is in `IRecipeManager` I'd expect it to be less problematic. Also I found a discord where I believe you could try asking: https://discord.blamejared.com/ - hopefully you find the solution, I would like to encourage posting it as it might help other people searching for it.